# vb.net write text to file ussing radio button

Tags: vb.net, text, radio-button

Hi I would like to know how i can write to the following file C:test.txt a specific string of text like "LANDSCAPE" if a radiobutton is clicked?

Comment: What have you tried?  What RadioButton are you talking about exactly?  Is this Winforms, ASP.NET, WPF, MVC, plain old HTML?

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the file if it already exists?  Will the file contain any other data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to create a file containing nothing but the text "LANDSCAPE", and you want to overwrite the file by that name if it already exists, then all you need to do is:

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        File.WriteAllText("C:\test.txt", "LANDSCAPE")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the file writing code to checked change event of the radio button.

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        'Write to file
    End If
End Sub
```